# Regex query - targeting two different parts of a URL, but not the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, single-page-application

I am trying to figure out the best regex to simply match two different parts of a URL. This is so I can run an A/B test on a particular area of the site (events) on a particular product page template that has multiple pages (go-).

For instance with [this](https://chillisauce.com/events/in-london/do-cocktail-making/go-d66d20fa2f3025289433) I just want to match 'events' and 'go-'

'go-' is the part of the URL that allows us to isolate our product pages and 'events' is our corporate business unit.

Thanks in advance,

Charlie

Comment: You mean you just want to check if the URL contains both `events` and `go-`, and in that order?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick `/events(?:\/[a-zA-Z-]+)+\/go-/`

Comment: Great, thanks, ilmirons. Don't worry if you don't have the time, but could you give me a brief description as to how it works so I can target other combinations of URLs?

Answer (score 0):

This will use groups to extract the information you want:

```
\/events\/([\w+-]*)\/.*\/go-(\w+)
```

Explaining:

`\/` - Catches the `/` character. Since it's a special character, we need to escape it with a backslash: `\`

`\w` - Matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_

`-` - Literally the `-` character

`*` - Quantifier (zero or more ocorrences)

`()` - Capture group

`.` - Any single character

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/eN7lQt/1)

[Regex101](http://Regex101) has a quick reference and is a very cool tool, with online validation, highlighting and such.

Comment: Great, thanks, Anderson. Don't worry if you don't have the time, but could you give me a brief description as to how it works so I can target other combinations of URLs?

Comment: Editted the answer, adding some explanation.